# Rewrite foreach loops into linq query?

Tags: c#, linq, loops

I tried to rewrite the following loops in one "elegant" linq query but no success!

```
foreach (Obj1 om in List1)
            {
                foreach (Obj2 ol in List2)
                {
                    if (ol.prop == value)
                    {
                       return om.prop
                    }
                }
            }
```

Could anyone suggest a query (if even possible)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What problem(s) did you have in your attempts, and what were those attempts?

Comment: Can you show us what you tried already?

Comment: Why do you even care? Linq will do the exact same thing like your code, which is pretty straightforward and easy to understand. You should care on *real* problems.

Comment: Do `List1` and `List2` relate to each other in any way? Because otherwise this code doesn't make much sense. If you never hit `if (ol.prop == value)` in the first loop of the outer foreach; then you won't hit it in any subsequent loop either. Given the current example, there is no point to the outer foreach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the snippet that produced exactly the same result as using loops:

```
result = List1.FirstOrDefault(om => om.List2.Any(ol => ol.prop == value))?.prop;
```

Thanks to everyone and especially to @Nekeniehl

Answer (score 0):

You can only convert one of those foreach:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var test = Get("yes");
    }

    public static object Get(string value)
    {
        List<Obj1> List1 = new List<Obj1>();
        List1.Add(new Obj1());

        List<Obj2> List2 = new List<Obj2>();
        List2.Add(new Obj2());

        return (from om in List1
                where List2.Any(ol => ol.prop == value)
                select om.prop).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}

public class Obj1
{
    public string prop => "not";
}

public class Obj2
{
    public string prop => "yes";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tareq, I was aware of this but I'm trying to figure if there is any way to get ride of all of em ,

Comment: Well, since you return on the first and you do not continue checking the others.. you can try something like

`var prop = List1.FirstOrDefault(om => List2.Any(ol => ol.prop == value)).prop`

Comment: (1) The `Where` doesn't make any sense. The boolean result will be the same for **every** `om`, since `om` doesn't matter for `List2.Any(ol => ol.prop == value)`. So you'll either get the **full** `List1`, or you'll get nothing (and thus not hit the return). (2) There is also no point to a foreach where the first loop returns from the method body.

Comment: The `where` will get the `om` when the `List2.Any` is `true`, but I'm not an expert on Linq, maybe you are right, I could not tested it.

Comment: @TareqB.: Maybe it's more obvious when you split the steps: `bool myBool = List2.Any(ol => ol.prop == value);` followed by `foreach (Obj1 om in List1.Where(om => myBool)) { ... }`

Comment: Hey @Flater, just out of curiosity I tested it, you are right, I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

`List2.SingleOrDefault(x => List1.Any(c => c == x));`

Obviosly insert what ever properties you want to compare. This would return the match or null. If you have multiple results, change SingleOrDefault to Where.

Answer (score 0):

i think it's gonna be something like that :

`Obj1 obj1 = list1.SingleOrDefault(l => l.list2.(j => j.prop == 1))`

Plus prop is attribute of the 2nd List not the 1st List.

You can found a great course of linq in this [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/walkthrough-writing-queries-linq)

Answer (score 0):

this code doesn't benefit from using nested loop and can increase app execution time if you didn't hit the condition in first iteration,

what you are trying to do can be summarized in this line (based on your code)

> you want to return the first element in `List1` if `list2` has `ol.prop==value`

based on that i would do this:

```
return List1.FirstOrDefault(om=> List2.Any(ol=>ol.prop == value))?.prop
```